# How to add values/names of checkbox to a variable on form submit?

Tags: php, arrays, string, forms, checkbox

I have a set of checkboxes in a form that has a submit button.

```
<form name="form" method="POST">
    <input type="checkbox" name="3" value="3">
    <input type="checkbox" name="7" value="7">
    <input type="checkbox" name="5" value="5">
    <input type="checkbox" name="12" value="12">
    <input type="submit" name="submit-form">
</form>

<?php 
if (isset($_REQUEST['submit-form'])) {

}
?>
...
```

The names/values that are currently in the code are dynamically generated and need to be kept (either in name or value will do).

When the form is submitted, I want to add the values or names of the checked checkboxes to a PHP variable, separated by commas, as a string.

Any help with the code that I should put in the if brackets would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is the check box added using jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the same name for the checkboxes as shown in below code:

```
<form name="form" method="POST">
    <input type="checkbox" name="numbers[]" value="3">
    <input type="checkbox" name="numbers[]" value="7">
    <input type="checkbox" name="numbers[]" value="5">
    <input type="checkbox" name="numbers[]" value="12">
    <input type="submit" name="submit-form">
</form>
```

And in process you can glue all the selected checkboxes using following code:

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['submit-form'])) {
     $allSelectedNumbers = implode(",", $_REQUEST['numbers']);
}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

If possible, use name="myValues[]", after POST, your $_POST['myValues'] will contain the array of all values that were selected. You can then do implode(",", $_POST['myValues']) to join them into 1 string.

Example:

```
<form name="form" method="POST">
    <input type="checkbox" name="options[]" value="3">
    <input type="checkbox" name="options[]" value="7">
    <input type="checkbox" name="options[]" value="5">
    <input type="checkbox" name="options[]" value="12">
    <input type="submit" name="submit-form">
</form>
...
<?php 
if (isset($_REQUEST['submit-form']) && !empty($_POST['options'])) {
    $myOptions = implode(", ", $_POST['options']);
}
```

?>

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

> `<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxarr[]" value="3">`

PHP:

> `<?php if (isset($_REQUEST['submit-form'])) 
>   {    print_r($_POST); }
>   ?>`

Answer (score 1):

Give proper name to your checkbox with array. Then get value using that name and implode to retrieve string

```
<form name="form" method="POST">
    <input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="3">
    <input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="7">
    <input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="5">
    <input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="12">
    <input type="submit" name="submit-form">
</form>

<?php 
if (isset($_REQUEST['submit-form'])) {
    $checkbox_val = $_POST["chk"];
    $checkbox_val = implode(",", $checkbox_val);
    echo $checkbox_val;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A lot of good answers here, but just to answer your question as it stands, in case modifying the HTML isn't an option for you.

```
<?php

  if (isset($_REQUEST['submit-form'])) {

    unset($_POST['submit-form']);
    echo implode( ',', $_POST );

  }
```